# Display li's through floating / display: inline-block

Tags: html, css, css-float, jsfiddle

trying to find out what the best way to go about setting up li's in an inline format either through `display: inline-block` or `float: left` 
Also i would like to be able to space out the li's with a small margin

Here is a JSfiddle of my current code:  http://jsfiddle.net/z1emdwnv/

Comment: please paste your code on StackOverflow too and please explain clearer what you want to acheive. E.g. I am creating this effect [effect.jpg] and I've done this but this didn't work for me.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a sample [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mrs_snow/9frr6wk9/1/)

```
ul.items li {
background-color: red;
float: left;
padding: 4px 10px;
list-style:none;
text-decoration: none;
margin: 0.5em;
}
```

Remove width:50% and add some padding to make it look nice and you should be good!

Answer (score 0):

Check this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/z1emdwnv/6/) with code

```css
*{box-sizing: border-box}
.focus_content {
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
 background-color: lightblue;
}
.sub_focus {

}
ul.items {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    font-size:0;
    line-height: 0;
}
ul.items li {
 
 display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: top;
 width: 50%;
    list-style:none;
    text-decoration: none;
    padding: 0.5em;
    font-size: 12px;
    line-height: 18px;
}
ul.items li .holder{background-color: red;}
```

```html
<div class="focus_content">
   <div class="sub_focus">     
    <ul class="items">
     <li><div class="holder">code</div></li>
     <li><div class="holder">code</div></li>
     <li><div class="holder">code</div></li>
     <li><div class="holder">code</div></li>    
    </ul>   
   </div>
   
  </div>
```